# Limit relationship field options to those authored by current member group

Tags: channel-entries, channel, member-management

I have a channel field that has a relationship to another channel. In cPanel, in the dropdown of the relationship field, I want it to only display the items in the other channel that was authored by the current member. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you set up authoring/editing restrictions under Member groups>[Your group]>Edit group under Channel posting privileges? "Can view channel entries authored by others", and "Can edit entries authored by others" set to "no".

Comment: @Bluedreamer I don't think this would work for relationships. If you try to create/edit a relationship field, the authors allowed is explicitly set there. This won't work for the OP's problem since the author restriction is based on who is logged in.